# php how to create a foreach loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 
        [test] => 145198
        [defender] => 5590478
        [stake] => 107
        [game_id] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 
        [test] => 145198
        [defender] => 5590478
        [stake] => 107
        [game_id] => 
    )
```

how to do a foreach loop for it?

so far i have:

```
 $mresults = $game_set->get_it();
foreach ($mresults as $key => $row)
{ ...dosomething}
```

but i believe i need to do another one inside this one.

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Why do you need another one inside it? What do you want to do? Why isn't `$row['defender']` (inside your current loop) enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach assigns the nested array to the $row variable and can be accessed like:

```
$row["test"]
$row["id"]
```

If you wish to loop again, you can do:

```
$mresults = $game_set->get_it();
foreach ($mresults as $key => $row)
{
    foreach($row as $k => $v)
    {
        echo $k." = ".$v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want to do, but try:

```
$mresults = $game_set->get_it();
foreach ($mresults as $key => $row) {
     echo "key: $key, row: $row\n";
}
```

To see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `$row` will contain that inner array, so you can output those values using `$row['test']`, `$row['defender']`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is all you need:

```
foreach ($game_set->get_it() as $game)
{
  echo $game['defender']."\n";
}
```